# React State is not assigning properly with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm creating a very basic todo app. But I'm getting an issue with pushing todos into an array and assigning them to the state.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todo : '',
      todos : []
    };
  };

  todoValue(todo){
    console.log(`Received the todo in the App : ${todo}`);
    this.setState({todo});
    console.log(this.state.todo);
  }
```

Here when I click a button I'm receiving `todo` value in `todo` argument of `todoValue` function. But it doesn't assign to the state on the event. It does assign the value to the state on next event.

As an example if I receive todo value as `one` in first event and todo value as `two` in next event this is what I'm getting.

[image: Screenshot of the output]

I want to assign the todo value to the state on the button click (not on the next event)

How can solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` [is an async operation but it does allow a callback to be triggered](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) when the operation is complete. Change your code to

```
this.setState({ todo }, () => console.log(this.state.todo));
```

and you'll see the latest changes you made to the state.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

setState is async, so react can batch several call to setState in order to improve performance.

As said above, either use the callback function of setState OR the componentLifeCycle `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.